# onClientItemRequested doesn't select default item

Tags: asp.net, jquery, telerik

I am trying to add default item 'All' to my RadComboBox. It is adding at the end and also it doesn't select this default item. What could be the problem? Are there any other ways to do it? Thank you..

```
function OnClientItemsRequested(sender, eventArgs) { 
      var combo = $find("<%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>"); 
      var intextput = "All"; 
      var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem(); 
      comboItem.set_text(intextput); 
      comboItem.set_value(""); 
      combo.trackChanges(); 

      combo.get_items().add(comboItem); 
      comboItem.select(); 
      combo.commitChanges(); 
      comboItem.scrollIntoView(); 
    } 

 <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="RadComboBox1"  
      EnableLoadOnDemand="true"  
      OnClientItemsRequested="OnClientItemsRequested"> 
      <WebServiceSettings Method="GetMyData" Path="http://localhost:1606/Service1.svc" /> 
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what's the `get_items()` function.

Shouldn't it be `combo.Items.add(comboItem);` ?

Comment: I tried to use combo.Items.add(comboItem) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I was able to add at the beginning of ComboBox but it doesn't get selected when the page loaded. I have to select dropdown arrow to this item.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [insert(index, comboItem) method](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combo_clientsideradcomboboxitemcollection.html) instead of add - it will give you the option to inject combo item as first. Something like the following:

```
 function OnClientItemsRequested(sender, eventArgs) { 
      var combo = $find("<%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>"); 
      var intextput = "All"; 
      var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem(); 
      comboItem.set_text(intextput); 
      comboItem.set_value(""); 
      combo.trackChanges(); 

      combo.get_items().insert(0, comboItem); 
      comboItem.select(); //not sure whether you need this line of code
      combo.commitChanges(); 
      comboItem.scrollIntoView(); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It is adding at the beginning of the ComboBox. But it doesn't get selected when the page loaded.